# How to reduce the file size/rendering performance of PDFs embedding large EPS?

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat

If one has a PDF with EPS-like graphics embedded.

The EPS-like is something like finite-element method plot or browian motion which takes quite a long time for the machine to render.

That makes the rendering of PDF slow/freezed.

Any suggestion to improve rendering performance(more scrolling/print efficient) on a Mac using some quartz filers or Adobe Acrobat?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a link to an example PDF file that you want to optimize... One really has to see the real problems with the file, otherwise one cannot suggest any helpful cures out of the blue sky.